# Points-to analysis - A definition

Tags: dependencies, call-graph, soot

I'm looking to perform some dependence analysis using a call-graph that I will build using the Soot framework. I read in a guide that using 'points-to' analysis can improve the precision of a call graph. What exactly is 'points-to' analysis and how could it improve the accuracy of a call-graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A key problem in understanding data flow is know what date each pointer can reference.  If you know nothing about a pointer to an object, and that object is updated via the pointer (e.g.,  p.=3) then it is possible that any object in your entire system might be modified.  If you know that p references a specific object O1, then you know that only O1 might be modified.  So knowledge of what p can point to, is important in understand side effects and the scope of such effects.

Now, imagine you have pointers to functions. If you don't know what a function pointer p points to,
and a function call is made indirectly through p, then any function might get called, and the side effects could be any side effect from any function.  If you know that p can only point to foo, then only the side effects that foo might cause can occur.

When computing a call graph, some function calls clearly only go to one place.  Some function calls can go to a variety of places because they are in fact function calls via pointers; "method" calls in OO languages are often like this and this is done on purpose to support polymorphism.

If you don't do points-to analysis, you can't possibly have done function-pointer points-to analysis.  That means your constructed call graph says a node bar might call many possible functions through its pointer p, which means there are many side effects you have to worry about.

A precise points-to analysis leads to precise function-points-to analysis, which leads to precise side effect analysis, which leads to better understanding of what the code can do.  Of course, precision is relative; and it is harder to get "very precise" points to analysis.  In the limit, it is impossible to get perfect points-to anlaysis; you are analyzing turing machines.

You can see some more discussion on flow analysis and an example of a "more precise" call graph at http://www.semdesigns.com/Products/DMS/FlowAnalysis.html